# Insertar a diferentes tablas de una base lo de un array en Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter-3

El problema que tengo es qué tengo obtengo un `json` de un formulario, al hacerle el `json decode` obtengo:

```
Array ( [curp_aval] => pemi940613hdfrdasr [nombre_aval] => Ivan [ap_pat_aval] => Perez
[ap_mat_aval] => Montiel [curp] => GACh940207hdasdfgh [nombre] => pablo javier 
[ap_pat] => gomez [ap_mat] => casol [telefono] => Array ( [0] => 1451234123 ) 
[correo] => Array ( [0] => a@q.qq ) [direccion] => 5 de febrero [no_ext] => 4 
[no_int] => - [codigo_postal] => 54506 [colonia] => cuaxoxa [demarcacion] => rio frio 
[entidad_federativa] => méxico [nivel_estudio] => Licenciatura [ocupacion] => estudiante )
```

Estos son los campos que insertare en mi tabla `usuario`, hasta este punto no tengo problema, el problema inicia cuando tengo q insertar los teléfonos que ingrese el usuario en mi tabla `agenda` y los correos que ingrese en mi tabla `correo`, no sé cómo hacer esa parte en mi modelo, ya que ando usando active récord.

*Controlador*

```
$data_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach ($data_array as $data_row)
```

*Modelo*

```
$this->db->insert('usuario', $data_row);
endforeach;
```

¿Cómo podría insertar esos datos en diferentes tablas?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías extraer el array de email y de telefonos, recorrerlos dentro del foreach que tienes e insertar donde lo necesites, y así queda tu foreach general por usuario, y dentro 2 foreach uno para email y otro para telefonos.